# How long it takes for a Mendeley Data repository review?

Tags: data, repository

I've just "published" some Datasets as the Mendeley Data repositories. After pressing the "Publish" button I was surprised with message that my dataset(s) are "in the moderation" process that I wasn't well aware of in advance (my bad).

Now, I'm puzzled how long it takes usually for Mendeley Data staff to approve a dataset/repository for being published on-line? Does someone has any experience with the service?

I planned to submit an article (linking to these dataset) today, but it seems I'll have to wait for the dataset moderation first.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mendeley Data moderated and accepted all 6 datasets, in between 2 and 3* days since submission.

- I can't say when exactly it was as I received no email confirmation and I've checked last time the status of datasets 2 days after submission. Also, looking on the Mendeley Data UI, I can't find any clue about when it was approved.

However, 3 days is very good in my opinion :)

Hope this info will help someone else :).
Live long and prosper!

Answer (score 3):

We hope to moderate datasets within 1-2 working days. We check that the dataset contains data files and not articles or spam.

If you have any questions, contact our team directly at data@mendeley.com

Best Regards,

Kate

Engagement Manager

Mendeley Data

Comment: Good, the quality of data sets is crucial for the service. Really, 3 days are more then good enough, in my view. Keep good work!